# Escape backslash in code block

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I just created [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52853102/967168) and am having a hard time escaping the backslash in order to keep the syntax highlighting consistent.

Normally I would just use double backslash, however in this instance both slashes show and it's not escaping.

However here I can write \ (double backslash) and only one shows.

I've tried experimenting with backticks but can't get anything to work.

Comment: Sorry, but you can't _escape_ a backslash with the current syntax highlighting system. It's just broken for T-SQL to be compatible with MySQL, you can either not use syntax highlighting at all (add `<!-- language: lang-none -->` in front of your code block), or accept broken syntax highlighting

Comment: You could move the broken line to the end of the code, so you can have as much proper highlighting as possible. I've just edited the answer to minimize the broken highlighting.